# Equation for determining a car's fuel consumption as well as cost

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Purchase price: 24000

Avg km/year: 40000

L/100 km: 5.3

Price of gas (per L):1.30

I was wondering what the formula is to find out how much litres of gas the car would consume as well as the cost of the car.

I've tried numerous equations but somehow failed to step into the correct formula. Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S: The answer is: `This car would use 10600.0 litres of gas and cost 37780.0 over 5 years.`

Comment: Elmer: Do not edit omit all the details of the question to render the question meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Cost of gas over five years:

$$(1)\;\;\dfrac{40000 \;\text{km}}{\text{year}}\times \dfrac{5.3\;\text{Liters}}{100 \;\text{km}}\times \underbrace{1.3}_{\text{cost per liter}} \times \underbrace{5}_{\text{years}}$$

$\text{Total cost to owner of car}\; = (1) + \;\text{purchase price}$.

Comment: This needs a TU! +1

Answer (score 3):

If your gas consumption is $\ell\text{ L/}100\text{ km}$, it’s $\frac{\ell}{100}\text{ L/km}$, so in driving $d\text{ km}$ you use $\frac{d\ell}{100}\text{ L}$ of gas. If the price per litre is $p$, you spend $\frac{d\ell p}{100}$ on gas in driving those $d\text{ km}$. If $\bar d$ is your average yearly driving distance in kilometres, and $n$ is the number of years that you drive, then $d=\bar dn$, so over a period of $n$ years you use $$\frac{\bar d\ell n}{100}$$ litres of gas and spend $$\frac{\bar d\ell np}{100}$$ on that gas. Here $\bar d=40000$, $\ell=5.3$, $n=5$, and $p=1.30$. The total cost of the car over that period is just what you spend on gas plus the purchase price of the car, which is $24000$.